# tcl command redirect to a variable, tcl version is 8.4

Tags: tcl, output-redirect

I want to redirect the output of 1 command to a variable, where the OUTPUT is usually to STDOUT. I am running an EDA tool, which has tcl interpeter & it's own commands.
Let's say that the tool has a tcl query, which says

```
TOOL> find_transistor m*
m1 m2 m3 m4
```

I want to have a way of doing the following:

```
TOOL> set ret redirect {find_transistor m*}
TOOL> puts $ret
m1 m2 m3 m4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you certain that find_transistor prints to stdout, or are you assuming that based on your interactive experience?

Answer (score 9):

This might work:

```
redirect -variable ret {find_transistor m*}

puts $ret
```

Comment: Well, this only works for tools of the company Synopsys. Probably it's still a good answer to keep, even if it does not answer the original question. At least it likely solves the issue for a lot of folks coming here. However `redirect` is not a plain Tcl command, and thus does not work in plain Tcl, and very unlikely in any other Tcl based EDA tools.

Comment: It is >10 years after this question was asked, but `redirect` also worked for me in Cadence's LEC tool, so this is not only limited Synopsys

Comment: Unfortunately not working in simulators - tried two separate vendors.  Also does not natively work in tclsh - at least the version distributed with MSYS2.

Answer (score 6):

well in pure Tcl

```
set ret [find_transistor m*]
```

would probably do what you want. Try reading the Tcl [tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl5.html).

Comment: This won't work if "find_transistor" writes its result to stdout. All your example does is save whatever `find_transistor` returns, which unfortunately is not what the question is asking.

Comment: You are of course correct - if the command really is writing to STDOUT then a different approach will be required.  We really need the originator of the question to come back and talk to us!

Comment: I'm not the originator of the question, but I encountered the same problem. [] will not work for some EDA tool internal commands and those commands do print messages to STDOUT. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way I've found is exec: set VAR [exec COMMAND]

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Should be on top. @LiorDagan, is this what you're looking for? I notice this question has no accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

If your application does not have a `redirect` command, you can create your own.

Please have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948274/923794) to the more [general question of how to redirect in plain Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531031/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-into-a-file-in-tcl)?

To redirect into a variable you could do:

```
proc redirect_variable {varname cmd} {
    rename puts ::tcl::orig::puts

    global __puts_redirect
    set __puts_redirect {}

    proc puts args {
        global __puts_redirect
        set __puts_redirect [concat $__puts_redirect [lindex $args end]]
        set args [lreplace $args end end]
        if {[lsearch -regexp $args {^-nonewline}]<0} {
            set __puts_redirect "$__puts_redirect\n"
        }
        return
    }

    uplevel $cmd

    upvar $varname destination
    set destination $__puts_redirect
    unset __puts_redirect

    rename puts {}
    rename ::tcl::orig::puts puts
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything mentioned here. Finally this is the one that actually worked for me:

```
redirect -variable <myvar> {puts [<some_tcl_command>] }
puts $<myvar>
```

PS: This worked in a Cadence tool.

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone comes up with an elegant solution, I share my ugly last resort:

```
find_transistor m* > tmp
set fp [open "tmp" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
```

Bear in mind that the output of the command should be relatively small.

Comment: This does not work in plain Tcl 8.4. Although I do assume that it fixes the problem for the original asker and lots of folks coming here, since several EDA tools implement shell like output redirection. Plain Tcl would choke on `test >f1` with `wrong # args: should be "test"` if `proc test {}  { puts "Hi, there!" }`