# Why is Tcl_Interprer implemented in such a way?

Tags: c++, tcl, implementation

```
int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 

    Tcl_Eval(interp, "close stdout");
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts hello");

    std::cout << "other output" << std::endl;
}
```

I have a program which uses `Tcl_Interpreter`. I don't want to see its output in stdout, so I am closing it. But it closes stdout of whole program and `"other output"` is not displayed too. My program could have lots of other outputs. Why Tcl interpreter disables it.

This kind of situation is when I am trying to evaluate `exit` command in interpreter. I expect that it should only destroy, delete or disable the interpreter, but it is calling `std::exit` which closes whole program, which retains undestructed objects.

I know that there may be workarounds to this situations but I am curios why does Tcl Interpreter implemented in such way. It would be more useful that it changes only itself, not the whole program.

Comment: Tcl was designed to be the scripting language glue for programs — that was its original design brief — and one of those things that code might want to do is `exit`. If you don't want `exit` to behave like that, delete or replace that command; Tcl's built-in `exit` is really just part of a “standard library” (like all the other commands) and isn't really all that special.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off redirecting the TCL output somewhere else rather than closing stdout:

- [stdout redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection)
- [How can I redirect stdout into a file in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531031/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-into-a-file-in-tcl)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an independent Tcl subprocess, you should start it with `system("tcl YourScript.tcl")`. When the interpreter runs in your process, it acts as part of your process.