# Redirect stdout to a file in tcl

Tags: redirect, tcl, io-redirection, tee, cisco-ios

I know this has been asked before.

But hear me out once..

I'm working on a Cisco router (IOS).

I have to write a script which executes some commands and redirect their output to a file. But instead of using `tee` for every command, I want to open a file then run the commands , whose output will be redirected to the file and then close the file.

And even the redirection operator `>` is not working or the following answer:

[How can I redirect stdout into a file in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531031/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-into-a-file-in-tcl/8532484#8532484)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the solutions in that question aren't working for you is informative: the *real* issue that you are experiencing is that Tcl commands do not normally write to `stdout` anyway (except for `puts`, which has that as its main job, and `parray`, which is a procedure that uses `puts` internally). The “write to `stdout`” that you are used to is a feature of the interactive Tcl shell only.

To capture the result of all commands while running a script, you need a wrapper like this:

```
trace add execution source leavestep log_result
proc log_result {cmd code result op} {
    puts stdout $result
}
source theRealScript.tcl
```

You'll find that it produces a *lot* of output. Cutting the output down is a rather useful thing, so this reduces it to just the immediately-executed commands (rather than everything they call):

```
trace add execution source enterstep log_enter
trace add execution source leavestep log_result
proc log_enter {args} {
    global log_depth
    incr log_depth
}
proc log_result {cmd code result op} {
    global log_depth
    if {[incr log_depth -1] < 1 && $result ne ""} {
        puts stdout $result
    }
}
source theRealScript.tcl
```

You'll probably still get far more output than you want…