# Redirecting the output to file in tickle script

Tags: linux, shell

As we have > for redirecting the output from the kernel to file in bash, Do we have any similar command in tickle?

Comment: `>` does not redirect output from kernel to bash. It puts std output to wherever you want them to be - file, /dev/null etc.

Comment: yaa similarly if we want to do redirection in tickle what we need to do ? Example: ls -l directory > file gives us the list of file and directories names from directory to file. Similarly is there any command in tcl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect stdout into a file in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531031/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-into-a-file-in-tcl)