# Tcl redirect stdout to file produces no output

Tags: tcl, stdout

Question is extension of what is answered in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531031/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-into-a-file-in-tcl/8532484#8532484). While trying to use it to print output with delay, `cat file_name` on the shell doesn't display the content of the file during the delay time using `after`. Here's the code:

```
proc foo {times} { 
    while {$times >0} {
        puts "hello$times"
        incr times -1
        after 20000
        puts "hello world" 
    }
}
proc reopenStdout {file} {
    close stdout
    open $file w        ;# The standard channels are special
}

reopenStdout ./bar
foo 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're writing is being buffered in memory and you're not writing enough of it to flush the internal buffer to disk. Add a `flush stdout` inside the loop in `foo`, or do something like set up the newly opened channel to be line-buffered:

```
proc reopenStdout {file} {
    close stdout
    set ch [open $file w]        ;# The standard channels are special
    chan configure $ch -buffering line
}
```

You can play with `chan configure`'s [`-buffering` and `-buffersize`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.html#M9) options to get the behavior that works best for your needs if line buffering isn't enough.

Comment: Yes i thought so too, but why does the `puts "hello world"`  in the original answer there was no need for flush? is that because the program/script reached end and an automatic flush was done?

Comment: @almostacoder Channels are flushed when they're closed, yeah (explicitly or at exit)